# How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables when column don't match properly

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

I've tried to find relevants informations but seems I can't figure this one by myself so I need assistance :)

For exemple, Table1 :

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+----------+
| ID    | SNA_Name    | Desc | Time      | Task_ID  |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+----------+
| 741   | Temp        | NNE  | 2015-01-. | 1661     |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+----------+
```

Table 2 :

```
+-------+-------------+
| ID    | Name        |
+-------+-------------+
| 741   | GRFDSD14    |
+-------+-------------+
```

Table 3 :

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
| xx    | USER        | xx   | xx        | Data                    |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
| xx    | Mylsef      | xx   | xx        | xxx.dd.1661 azerty      |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

I would like to have something like this at the end :

```
(----------TABLE 1----------------------)(--Table 2---)(---TABLE 3---) 
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| ID    | SNA_Name    | Desc | Time      | Name        | USER        |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 741   | Temp        | NNE  |  2015-01-.| GRFDSD14    | Mylsef      |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

So far i've tried to match TABLE 1 and 2 like this using the same ID **741**

```
SELECT a.ID, a.SNA_Name, a.Desc, a.Time, b.Name
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
on a.ID = b.ID
```

RESULT :

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------+
| ID    | SNA_Name    | Desc | Time      | Name        |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------+
| 741   | Temp        | NNE  |  2015-01-.| GRFDSD14    |
+-------+-------------+------+-----------+-------------+
```

But to join the third Table I need to match with the Task_ID information : 1661
In the third Table, my ID is surrender by numbers so I can't use the symbol =
And I want to print the Column USER in the same row where Data match with Task_ID

Thanks a lot.

[Edit -> Using SQL 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the join:

```
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Data LIKE '%'+ CAST(Table1.Task_ID AS varchar(20)) + '%'
```

Comment: That took 1.06 Minute to query my base but works very Well !

Much Much appreciate André Kops !!! You made my day after few hours searching ! I could definitely not figured this out by mylself !

Now I need to understand how this arguments works, that is an other story :)

Comment: One note here you should know about: e.g. ID 166 would also find this rec. If it always has a dot in front and a space after you should add those to the pattern: LIKE '%.'+ CAST(Table1.Task_ID AS varchar(20)) + ' %'

Comment: ID 1661 has not always a dot in front and a space after, sometimes a space before, sometimes a number, sometimes à ' so, I wanted to explore the whole possibility to find any number. Thank you André

Comment: OK please note if you have e.g. a rec in Table1 for ID 661 the LIKE will also find the rec in Table3 with text "xxx.dd.1661 azerty" as well as it contains text "661". You'd need to modify the pattern a bit to prevent that, provided you can think up logic that will always work - I guess if the character before the 1661 can be a number, this will be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what database you are using, so I can't give specifics, but I would try to create a calculated column using a regular expression that is able to compare for any of the situations you describe, thosae being...

sometimes the number has a period before it, sometimes it has a space before it, sometimes it has an apostrophe before it.

In the example below, the regular expression will check for any combination of the id with any of the above characters preceding it, and it also prevents mismatching from partial values - i.e. it will not match 56 and 4564.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   t1
LEFT JOIN 
    t2
ON 
    concat(t2.data, ' ') REGEXP concat('[\'. ]', t1.i2, ' ')
```

Some notes on the above - I concat a space onto the data column so that I always am guaranteed to have either the number followed by a space, or the number followed by some other text (like your "azerty").  I concat a space on the end of the id so that it will prevent matches where the same id is embedded in another value.

I hope this is helpful for someone.